# How to detect if my service is running in a TSE session?

Tags: c++, windows, session

I have written a service that should behave in a special way when running on a TSE server, **in session 0**.

My lookups on the Internet gave me the following function:

```
GetSystemMetrics(SM_REMOTESESSION)
```

Which indeed returns `TRUE` when my service is running in an user session on the TSE server. However, it still returns `FALSE` when the service is run in the session 0.

As I understand things, `GetSystemMetrics` is more or less related to UI, so it makes sense that it doesn't return `TRUE` for the session 0, since this session should not *draw* anything.

Is there any other way to reliably determine if my service is running under the session 0 and on a TSE server ?

Thank you.

The operating system is Windows 2008 server.

Comment: On Windows Server 2008 all services will running in session 0.  If you want to be sure you can use ProcessIdToSessionId() to get the session that your service's process is running in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **quick hack** is to see if the CLIENTNAME and SESSIONNAME environment variables are set.

The catch is that it [might not be available](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2509192) when launched in a separate process on the server, but since you are on W2K8 you should be fine.